# jsTree Contextmenu not displaying all options due to location on browser window

Tags: contextmenu, jstree

The web application that I'm working with consists of a jsTree (v3.1.1) with the contextmenu plugin. This is all working correctly, but when I right click on a node that is close to the bottom of the page it cuts off some options. See image below:

[Contextmenu on jsTree getting cut off if too close to the bottom of the browser window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s0ywU.png)

I have had a look at the jsTree API [Show at Node](https://www.jstree.com/api/#/?q=$.jstree.defaults.contextmenu&f=$.jstree.defaults.contextmenu.show_at_node), but this just specify whether the context menu should display below the selected node or at the position of the mouse click.

If someone could please provide me with some guidance on how to calculate that if there is not enough space for the entire context menu to be displayed (all options visible), to display it in such a way that the user is able to see all the options. If a node is selected and there is enough space for the context menu, it should work like it is currently by default.

So I know what to do, but it is the how & where I'm not sure on how to implement it on the jsTree where I'm struggling:

1. Get location of the node selected
2. Determine height of the context menu
3. Determine available space from the select node to the bottom of the browser window
4. If available space is less that that of the context menu, display the context menu to the top of the node. If there is no space issue, display as it does currently.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surely there is a more elegant solution but you may wait for it quite long.
As a quick fix I propose simply to move the context menu to the position you want after it is shown. A user won't notice it anyway. See below and check fiddle - [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/qagwejsc/). Probably you would want to check if node is at screen bottom before moving menu which I haven't done.

```
$("#dutchData")
.on("show_contextmenu.jstree", function (e, data) {
        var $node = $('#'+data.node.id),
            $menu = $('.vakata-context').first(),
            nodeTop = $node.offset().top,
            menuTop = nodeTop + $node.height() - $menu.height(),
            menuLeft = 200,
            $subMenu = $menu.find('ul'),
            subMenuTop = $menu.height()-$subMenu.height();

    $menu.offset({left: menuLeft, top: menuTop });
    $subMenu.offset({top: subMenuTop });

})
.jstree({
    "core" : {
       "data" : data,
        "themes": {
            "url": true,
            "icons": true
        }
    },
    plugins: ['contextmenu']
});
```